# please explain this binary search function for me

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bit-shift

below is Apple's code for generic binary search.
I am not good with bit manipulation etc, so this is really hard for me to understand.
I have commented in the code below the parts I do understand

1. What is base? is this the array containing the values?
2. if nremain is the number of values in the array not having been analyzed, why are we rightshifting this by 1 every iteration?
3. also please help me understand what the first line of the forloop is. so my guess is p points to the midpoint of the remaining elements but I don't get the (nremain >>1) * width part. What is width? how does multiplying rightshifted-by-1 version of nremain with width set the pointer to the the midpoint?
4. sign > 0 when key > p and pointer needs to move to the next element. How is this achieved by doing p + width? Again, knowing what width is would be super helpful.
5. I get the we are subtracting from nremain by 1 at the end of every iteration to signify one element having been analyzed, but what is the point of nremain>>=1 every iteration in this case?

Thanks in advance! I look forward to hearing back from anyone.

```
void *apple_bsearch(const void *key, const void *base, size_t nmemb,  
               size_t width, int (*compar)(const void *, const void *)) {
    for (size_t nremain = nmemb; nremain != 0; nremain >>= 1) {
        void *p = (char *)base + (nremain >> 1) * width; // I don't get this
        // this is comparing key & where currently p is pointing
        int sign = compar(key, p); 
        if (sign == 0) { // if p and key are equal, sign is 0
            return p;
        }
        if (sign > 0) {  // when key > p, move right
            base = (char *)p + width;
            nremain--;
        }       
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll make certain assumption (based on informed guessing I'd say):

1. `nmemb` is the number of members of the array
2. `width` is equal to `sizeof(array[0])`
3. `base` is pointing to the first member of the array, *i.e.*, `base == array[0]`
4. the array is sorted (from smallest to biggest value)

Note that bitshifting to the right is basically integer division (it discards the remainder, *e.g.*, `3 >> 1 == 1`).

The function takes the following arguments:

- `key`, pointer to const void
- `base`, pointer to const void
- `nmemb`, size_t variable
- `width`, size_t variable
- `compar`, (a pointer) to a function with two arguments (2x pointer to `const void`) that returns an `int`

The fact that pointers to `void` are used allows the function to be agnostic about the size of the elements of an array (and thus, be generic).

Now let's go line by line.

1. The `for` loop initializes `nremain` as `nmemb`, and it loops until `nremain != 0` (or a `return` occurs). And the end of a loop it divides `nremain` by 2, rounding the result down (right shift by 1).
2. `p` is declared as a pointer to `void` set at the base offset by half of `nremain` (number of array elements to be considered) times `width`. Thus `p` will point to the end of the left half of the array. For example, if there are 7 elements in the array, in the first iteration `p` will point to the 4th element. The cast `(char *) base` just makes sure that the correct number of bytes is added, assuming that `width == sizeof(array[0])`, since `sizeof(char) == 1`.
3. `compar` then compares `p` with `key` and on success `p` is returned.
4. If `p < key` then `base` is set to the next member after the one pointed to by `p` and 1 is subtracted from `nremain`. Here's an explanation due to  [Eric Postpischil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/298225/eric-postpischil): "The prior assignment to `p` effectively partitions the array into three pieces: The element pointed to by `p`, the elements earlier than that, and the elements after that. The number of elements earlier is `nremain>>1`, the number exactly at `p` is `1`, and the number after it is `(nremain-1)>>1`. *E.g.*, if `nremain` is 12, the parts have 6, 1, and 5 elements. Subtracting 1 from `nremain` at that point ensures it is set correctly by the `nremain >>= 1` step for the next iteration."
5. Reiterate.
6. If we don't find the value and exit the `for` loop (notice that when `nremain == 1` at the end of the loop `nremain >> 1 == 0`), return `NULL`.

Maybe I'm wrong in some of the assumptions, so you'll want to work the code out by changing them ;). Hope this helps!

Comment: 4 is stated incorrectly. The prior assignment to `p` effectively partitions the array into three pieces: The element pointed to by `p`, the elements earlier than that, and the elements after that. The number of elements earlier is `nremain>>1`, the number exactly at `p` is 1, and the number after it is `(nremain-1)>>1`. E.g., if `nremain` is 12, the parts have 6, 1, and 5 elements. Subtracting 1 from `nremain` at that point ensures it is set correctly by the `nremain >>= 1` step for the next iteration.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for correcting me, I corrected my answer by quoting your comment instead of my previous explanation.

Comment: is there a way to find the number of elements right to the base (base inclusive) if the key wasn't found in the loop?

Comment: @codeholeishere If I understand your question correctly, than that would be `nmemb`